# Why a mounted encrypted volume with bitlocker is accessible as if it weren't encrypted at all?

Tags: bitlocker

When we encrypt a volume with bitlocker, it takes time to encrypt the data according to the amount of the data but Once the encrypted volume is mounted the contents are transparently accessible to software running on the device as if it weren't encrypted at all.why? I know if I want to turn off bitlocker on that volume it would take some time as same as turning on bitlocker on that volume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitlocker is like an adapter: encrypted data comes in, unencrypted data goes out. And vice versa.

A filesystem is an abstraction. It creates a layer between the data on the storage device and the application, so accessing a NTFS formatted SSD and accessing a FAT12 formatted floppy disk uses the same procedures.

Bitlocker works like another abstraction layer. It stays bellow the filesystem, so the storage media is encrypted and decrypted by Bitlocker on the fly, all the filesystem sees is unencrypted data, all the storage device sees is encrypted data.

Answer (score 1):

Bitlocker encrypts the entire filesystem. When the operating system is running, it decrypts on the fly sections of the disk as they are accessed, giving the user an experience as if the disk is not encrypted at all.